Pythonnet running with conda environment
I am trying to run a function in a script.py from a program.cs via pythonnet.
I want to use a python exe and a python dll from a conda environment named "playground".
The code is quite simple (and it works using system python exe):
using Python.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using static System.Formats.Asn1.AsnWriter;

string pythonDll = @"python310.dll";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", pythonDll);
PythonEngine.Initialize();

PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();

RunScript("sqlite_unpack_interactive", "main");

static void RunScript(string scriptName, string methodName)
{

    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        dynamic os = Py.Import("os");
        dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");

        sys.path.append(@"C:\Users\gianmaria_c\OneDrive - Promau Srl\Code\CS\InterOps-Sqlite");

        var pythonScript = Py.Import(scriptName);
        var r = pythonScript.InvokeMethod(methodName);
    }
}

The console outputs the following :
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\gianmaria_c\\OneDrive - Promau Srl\\Code\\CS\\InterOps-Sqlite\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\InterOps-Sqlite.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\gianmaria_c\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\gianmaria_c\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\gianmaria_c\\OneDrive - Promau Srl\\Code\\CS\\InterOps-Sqlite\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\InterOps-Sqlite.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\gianmaria_c\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\gianmaria_c\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\gianmaria_c\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\python310.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\gianmaria_c\\OneDrive - Promau Srl\\Code\\CS\\InterOps-Sqlite\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00006f0c (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>

From the console I can correctly import the packages in my env, so I suppose It is working in vs
I tried running the script from different conda envs (with different python versions), same error.
I tried running the script from system python, PythonEngine.Initialize() works.
what am I doing wrong?
